# Spring Properties not Loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot for the first time and using xml less config as well.

Trying to add properties file value in my bean class but getting `null` values. Here is my code:

config.java:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private static SpringAppProp springAppProp;





    @Value("${url}")
    private static String url;

    @Value("${driverClassName}")
    private static String driverClassName;

    @Value("${username}")
    private static String username;

    @Value("${password}")
    private static String password;

    @Value("${initialSize}")
    private static int initialSize;

    @Value("${maxActive}")
    private static int maxActive;

    @Value("${dbPort}")
    private static int dbPort;

    @Value("${dbServiceName}")
    private static String dbServiceName;

    @Value("${dbServer}")
    private static String dbServer;



    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
    @Bean(name = "DataSource")
    public static BasicDataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setUrl(url);
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        basicDataSource.setInitialSize(initialSize);
        basicDataSource.setMaxTotal(maxActive);
        basicDataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
        basicDataSource.setMinIdle(0);
        basicDataSource.setMaxWaitMillis(15000);
        return basicDataSource;
      }

}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
username=XXXX
password=XXXX
initialSize=10
maxActive=20
dbPort=XXX
dbServiceName=xxxx
dbServer=xxxxxx
url=jdbc:oracle:thin@//xxxxx
```

Can someone see and let me know what i am doing wrong here..

Comment: First drop the static, then remove your whole class. You are using Spring Boot that already configures a `DataSource` and already reads the `application.properties`. Work with the framework instead of around it.

Comment: How do i do that.. Can you give me a working code.. Also i would need proeprties to read some other properties besides datasource

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `static`s from fields that you've annotated with `Value`:

```
@Value("${url}")
private String url;

@Value("${driverClassName}")
private String driverClassName;
```

And since you're using Spring Boot, there is no need for `@PropertySource`.

**Update** As M. Deinum said, it's better to drop your configuration class altogether and use `spring.datasource.*` properties in your `application.properties`.

Comment: server.port=8080
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
#removeAbandoned=true
spring.datasource.initialSize=10
spring.datasource.maxActive=20
spring.datasource.dbPort=xxxx
spring.datasource.dbServiceName=xxxxxx
spring.datasource.dbServer=xxxxxxx
spring.datasource.url= xxxxx
#management.port = 9080
And Code has been changed like this
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
 public  String DBurl;
 @Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
 public  String driverClassName1;
But still value is coming like null

Comment: After using `spring.datasource.*` properties, there is no need for injecting them to another class, spring will instantiate an instance of `DataSource` for you,,

Comment: Thanks for the answer